# Tensorflow placeholder changing results

Tags: python, tensorflow, placeholder

I am learning tensorflow for one week now and trying to make a class for CNN starting from a code from stanford (code below)

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from time import time


class Cnn:

def __init__(self, batch_size=128, skip_step=10, epochs=1, dropout_ratio=0.75):
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.skip_step = skip_step
    self.epochs = epochs
    self.dropout_ratio = dropout_ratio
    self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name="X_placeholder")
    self.images = tf.reshape(self.x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])
    self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name="Y_placeholder")
    self.predictions = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name="predictions")
    self.dropout = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="dropout")
    self.global_step = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False, name='global_step')
    self.layers = [self.images]
    self.n_layers = 0

def convolution(self, kernel_size, n_output,  strides, scope_name):
    previous_layer = self.layers[self.n_layers]
    with tf.variable_scope(scope_name) as scope:
        kernel_shape = [kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1], previous_layer.get_shape()[3], n_output]
        kernel = tf.get_variable("kernels", kernel_shape,
                                 initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer())
        biases = tf.get_variable("biases", [n_output],
                                 initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
        convolution_2d = tf.nn.conv2d(previous_layer, kernel, strides=strides,
                                      padding="SAME")
        convolution = tf.nn.relu(convolution_2d + biases, name=scope.name)
    self.layers.append(convolution)
    self.n_layers += 1
    return convolution

def pool(self, size, strides, scope_name, padding="SAME"):
    previous_layer = self.layers[self.n_layers]
    with tf.variable_scope(scope_name):
        pool = tf.nn.max_pool(previous_layer, ksize=size, strides=strides,
                              padding=padding)
    self.layers.append(pool)
    self.n_layers += 1
    return pool

def fully_connected(self, n_input, n_output, scope_name, relu=False, dropout=True):
    previous_layer = self.layers[self.n_layers]
    with tf.variable_scope(scope_name):
        weights = tf.get_variable("weights", [n_input, n_output],
                                  initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer())
        biases = tf.get_variable("biases", [n_output],
                                 initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
        pool_reshaped = tf.reshape(previous_layer, [-1, n_input])
        logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(pool_reshaped, weights), biases)
        fc = logits
        if relu:
            fc = tf.nn.relu(fc, name="relu")
        if dropout:
            fc = tf.nn.dropout(fc, self.dropout, name="dropout")
    self.layers.append(fc)
    self.n_layers += 1
    if relu is False and dropout is False:
        self.logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(pool_reshaped, weights), biases, name="logits")
        self.predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="predictions")
    return fc

def set_loss(self, scope_name):
    previous_layer = self.layers[self.n_layers]
    with tf.name_scope(scope_name):
        entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=previous_layer, labels=self.y)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(entropy, name='loss')
    self.layers.append(loss)
    self.n_layers += 1
    self.loss = loss

def set_optimizer(self):
    previous_layer = self.layers[self.n_layers]
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(previous_layer, global_step=self.global_step)
    self.layers.append(optimizer)
    self.n_layers += 1
    self.optimizer = optimizer

def run(self, train_x, train_y):
    sess = tf.Session()
    with sess.as_default():
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./my_graph/mnist', sess.graph)
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(os.path.dirname('results/checkpoint'))
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        initial_step = self.global_step.eval()

        start_time = time()

        n_batches = int(train_x.shape[0] / self.batch_size)
        total_correct_preds = 0
        total_loss = 0.0
        current_position = 0
        for index in range(initial_step, int(n_batches * self.epochs)):  # train the model n_epochs times
            x_batch = train_x[current_position: current_position + self.batch_size, :]
            y_batch = train_y[current_position: current_position + self.batch_size, :]
            feed_dict = {self.x: x_batch, self.y: y_batch, self.dropout: self.dropout_ratio}
            _, loss_batch, logits_batch = sess.run([self.optimizer, self.loss, self.logits],
                                                   feed_dict=feed_dict)
            total_loss += loss_batch
            preds = tf.nn.softmax(logits_batch)
            correct_preds = tf.equal(tf.argmax(preds, 1), tf.argmax(y_batch, 1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(correct_preds, tf.float32))
            total_correct_preds += sess.run(accuracy)

            if (index + 1) % self.skip_step == 0:
                print('Average loss at step {}: {:5.1f}'.format(index + 1, total_loss / self.skip_step))
                total_loss = 0.0
                saver.save(sess, 'results/mnist-convnet', index)
            current_position += self.batch_size

        print("Optimization Finished!")  # should be around 0.35 after 25 epochs
        print("Total time: {0} seconds".format(time() - start_time))
        print("Accuracy {0}".format(total_correct_preds / train_x.shape[0]))

def test(self, val_x, val_y):
    print("start testing")
    checkpoint_file = tf.train.latest_checkpoint("results/")
    graph = tf.Graph()
    with graph.as_default():
        sess = tf.Session()
        with sess.as_default():
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("{}.meta".format(checkpoint_file))
            saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file)
            self.x = graph.get_operation_by_name("X_placeholder").outputs[0]
            self.y = graph.get_operation_by_name("Y_placeholder").outputs[0]
            self.dropout = graph.get_operation_by_name("dropout").outputs[0]
            self.global_step = graph.get_operation_by_name("global_step").outputs[0]
            self.logits = graph.get_operation_by_name("logits").outputs[0]

            current_position = 0
            n_batches = int(val_x.shape[0] / self.batch_size)
            total_correct_preds = 0
            for i in range(n_batches):
                x_batch = val_x[current_position: current_position + self.batch_size]
                y_batch = val_y[current_position: current_position + self.batch_size]
                feed_dict = {self.x: x_batch, self.y: y_batch, self.dropout: self.dropout_ratio}
                logits_batch = sess.run(self.logits, feed_dict=feed_dict)
                preds = tf.nn.softmax(logits_batch)
                correct_preds = tf.equal(tf.argmax(preds, 1), tf.argmax(y_batch, 1))
                accuracy = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(correct_preds, tf.float32))
                total_correct_preds += sess.run(accuracy)

                current_position += self.batch_size
            print("Accuracy {0}".format(total_correct_preds / val_x.shape[0]))
```

testing code

```
from cnn import Cnn

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

tf.set_random_seed(1)

N_CLASSES = 10

# load datas
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("mnist", one_hot=True)
train_x, train_y = mnist.train.images, mnist.train.labels
val_x, val_y = mnist.test.images, mnist.test.labels

model = Cnn(batch_size=128, skip_step=10, epochs=0.25, dropout_ratio=0.75)

model.convolution(kernel_size=[5, 5], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], n_output=32, scope_name="conv1")
model.pool(size=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], scope_name="pool1")
model.convolution(kernel_size=[5, 5], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], n_output=64, scope_name="conv2")
model.pool(size=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], scope_name="pool2")
input_features = 7 * 7 * 64
model.fully_connected(n_input=input_features, n_output=1024, scope_name="fc", relu=True, dropout=True)
model.fully_connected(n_input=1024, n_output=N_CLASSES, scope_name="softmax_linear", dropout=False)
model.set_loss(scope_name="loss")
model.set_optimizer()
model.run(train_x=train_x, train_y=train_y)
model.test(val_x, val_y)
```

Commenting the line
self.predictions = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name="predictions") change the results of the training.

Someone already had this problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you paste also the code that you run for training? Here you only pasted the code describing the cnn class. I don't see any place where self.predictions is used, so it is a bit strange (unless the changes that you get are minor).

Comment: thats the thing, i only assign predictions in function fully_connected
i never use it anywhere else (but edited with the code to test)

Comment: And how much are the results of your training change when you commented the line? That is, was it a minor change or a major change?

Comment: first loss goes from 30000 to 37000

Comment: And later losses? Because there is some randomness in the process (that is, weights are initialized randomly), so I am wondering if the changes that you see are just due to this randomness. For example, if you train several times with and without commenting this line, do you always have the same type of difference?

Comment: Didnt try that as i use a seed. Should i have those difference if the seed is the same ?

Comment: O I just saw your edit with the seed. Well, I can't think about any other reason than randomness... (the randomness is not only due to initializer, it can also come from the dropout for example).

Comment: Ok maybe then i ll run the 2 with more epoch and see if there is a convergence
Thanks you again